# Creating new account with or without ModelForms and designing with HTML/CSS

Tags: python, html, css, django

Is it best practice or necessary to create a new user using ModelForms in Django? What I have done is create a form in HTML and have that form POST to a function in one of my views to create an account. The reason I am asking this is because I am new to Django and upon playing with Django, I am not sure if ModelForms allow the flexibility of designing and decorating the generate HTML compared to if I create the form myself in HTML/CSS.

user model:

```
class BeeradUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activation_code = models.CharField(max_length=36)
```

registration function:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        firstname = request.POST.get("firstname")
        lastname = request.POST.get("lastname")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password")


        payload = {
            "username": username,
            "firstname": firstname,
            "lastname": lastname,
            "email": email,
            "password": password
        }
        try:
            unique_key = str(uuid.uuid4())

            user = User(username=username, first_name=firstname, last_name=lastname, email=email, password=password)
            # Modified User class
            new_user = BeeradUser(user=user, activation_code=unique_key)
        except TypeError as e:
            return render(request, "error/404.html")
        return render(request, "success.html", {"payload": payload})

    else:
        print "there"
        poop = {"data": "sdfsdf"}
        return render(request, "fail.html", {"payload": poop})
```

form:

```
<form class="signup-form" method="post" action="/auth/signup/" id="create-account">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input id="signup-username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
   <input id="signup-firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
   <input id="signup-lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
   <input id="signup-email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
   <input id="signup-password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"><div id="pswd-msg"></div>
   <input id="signup-confirm-password" name="confirm-password" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password"><div id="result"></div>
   <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-xl" id="create-acc-btn" name="signup-submit">Create Account</button>
</form>
```

Obviously, the registration function does not `save()` the User to the database yet but I was wondering if this is the right approach versus using ModelForms

Answer (score 1):

You didnt saved it.Try this to create `new User`

```
user = User(username=username, first_name=firstname, last_name=lastname, email=email, password=password)
user.save()
```

Also

```
new_user = BeeradUser(user=user, activation_code=unique_key)
new_user.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

So, what happens when your user fails to enter all the required fields? Or enters something that isn't an email address in the `email` field? Your code will blithely create the user anyway, even though that instance would be invalid.

The main responsibility of forms is to validate data. That's especially important when it comes to something like creating users and adding passwords. The only difference your fields have over those automatically created by a Django form is the `placeholder` attribute, which you can easily set yourself in the form description.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the data validation importance of forms. I guess I should have asked the question differently. Right now I am using some JAvaScript to do somethings such as disabling the submit button or password matching. Because the forms are generated automatically, and still learning Django, I'm not sure how I would integrate JavaScript logic and CSS if I wanted to do so.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure if ModelForms allow the flexibility of designing and decorating the generate HTML compared to if I create the form myself in HTML/CSS.

&

> I was wondering if this is the right approach versus using ModelForms

Django offers a [great tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial04/) which covers some of your question and there's also [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/), which holds all the answers you seek, but here's the ***TL;DR*** version:

### Yes, Django offers all. And no, that is not the right approach.

Django `ModelForm` class objects' main goal is to connect the `Model` class objects to the HTML `<form>` and act as a median class, where you can test the fields with more than just database requirements. It offers functionalities like raising errors and making API calls for syncing things like captcha, which will happen in the back-end and not in the plain site of the user (html/css/javascript).

It does, as you've pointed out, allow auto generated fields and things of that nature, but those are more of a feature than they are it's purpose. And those can still be designed and decorated with your own HTML/CSS, but the back-end features I mentioned earlier will be unavailable..